# Dynamic array functions

Tags: excel, dynamic-arrays

I have four dynamic columns (A:D). But I need to search every row with xmatch and I am not sure how to do it dynamically. I have tried XMATCH("A";A1:D1#) but it is not working. I tried to use offset function XMATCH("A";OFFSET(A1#;0;0;1;4)) but it will not spill. Any idea what to do?

Comment: Pretty sure the lookup_array on MATCH or XMATCH needs to be a single row or column of cells, so maybe use four XMATCHs joined using IFERROR.

Comment: Well it is single row, but I need the row spill down same as dynamic column...

Comment: Any spill would make it multiple rows I guess and Excel would interpret the spill to the range A1:D12, or however far it spills.